# How to return list of models in EF Core with two related columns in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I was trying to get the list of student sanctions in `usersanctions` table it has two related columns the `StudentId` and `SanctionId`.

My `StudentModel` class:

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public int StudentId {  get; set; }
    public List<UserSanctionModel> Sanctions { get; set; } = new List<UserSanctionModel>();
}
```

`UserSanctionModel` which has two related columns

```
public class UserSanctionModel
{
    public int UserSanctionId { get; set; }
    public int SanctionId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public SanctionModel Sanction { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Lastly the `SanctionModel`

```
public class SanctionModel
{
    public int SanctionId { get; set; }
    public string SanctionName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Below is my EF `include` and I was thinking it will get the list of sanctions because it has a column of `StudentId` and `SanctionId`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<StudentModel>>> GetStudents(FilterParameter param)
{
    return await _context.Students
                         .Include(us => us.Sanctions)
                         .ThenInclude(s => s.Sanction)
}
```

And I was wondering why EF create a new column in my database:

```
SELECT 
    [s].[StudentId], [s].[CourseId], [s].[DepartmentId], 
    [s].[SectionId], [s].[StudentName], [s].[YearLevel], 
    [c].[CourseId], [c].[CourseName], [c].[ShortcutName], 
    [d].[DepartmentId], [d].[DepartmentName], [s0].[SectionId], 
    [t].[UserSanctionId], [t].[SanctionId], [t].[StudentId], 
    [t].[StudentModelStudentId], [t].[SanctionId0], 
    [t].[SanctionName], [s0].[SectionName]
FROM 
    [Students] AS [s]
INNER JOIN 
    [Courses] AS [c] ON [s].[CourseId] = [c].[CourseId]
INNER JOIN 
    [Departments] AS [d] ON [s].[DepartmentId] = [d].[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN 
    [Sections] AS [s0] ON [s].[SectionId] = [s0].[SectionId]
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT [u].[UserSanctionId], [u].[SanctionId], [u].[StudentId], [u].[StudentModelStudentId], [s1].[SanctionId] AS [SanctionId0], [s1].[SanctionName]
      FROM [UserSanctions] AS [u]
      INNER JOIN [Sanctions] AS [s1] ON [u].[SanctionId] = [s1].[SanctionId]
  ) AS [t] ON [s].[StudentId] = [t].[StudentModelStudentId] //I gues this line
  ORDER BY [s].[StudentId], [c].[CourseId], [d].[DepartmentId], [s0].[SectionId], [t].[UserSanctionId]
```

This is the column `StudentModelStudentId` which should be `StudentId`

Comment: efcore needs foreignkey when using include linq. The foreignkey and one-to-many relationship can also be defined on context modelcreating https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/foreign-and-principal-keys#foreign-keys.      modelBuilder.Entity<UserSanctionModel>()
                .HasOne(a => a.Student)
                .WithMany(b => b.Sanctions)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.StudentId);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this thread on the internet which says we need to assign foreign key in the properties and the model

```
public class UserSanctionModel
{
  public int UserSanctionId { get; set; }
  public int SanctionId { get; set; }
  public SanctionModel Sanction { get; set; } = new();

  //This fixed my migrations and query
  public int StudentId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
  public StudentModel Student { get; set; }
}
```